# What's the difference between super().method() and self.method()

Tags: python, python-3.x

What's the difference between using `super().method()` and `self.method()`, when we inherit something from a parent class and why use one instead of another?

The only thing that comes to my mind is that with static methods it becomes obviously impossible to call `self.method()`. As for everything else I can't come up with justification to use `super()`.

Could someone present a dummy example when choosing one over another matters and explain why, or is it just convention thing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **self**

**self**, which is mostly used as the first parameter of instance methods of classes, always represents the calling object/instance of the class.

> **super()**

**super()** refers to object of parent class. It is useful in case of method overriding and this is in case of numerous programming languages including C++, Java etc. In Java, **super()** is used to call the constructor of parent class.

Please have a look at the below little example.

```
class TopClass(object):
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name;
        self.age = age;

    def print_details(self):
        print("Details:-")
        print("Name: ", self.name)
        print("Age: ", self.age)
        self.method()

    def method(self):
        print("Inside method of TopClass")

class BottomClass(TopClass):
    def method(self):
        print("Inside method of BottomClass")    

    def self_caller(self):
         self.method()

    def super_caller(self):
         parent = super()
         print(parent)
         parent.method()

child = BottomClass ("Ryan Holding", 26)
child.print_details()

"""
Details:-
Name:  Ryan Holding
Age:  26
Inside method of BottomClass
"""

parent = TopClass("Rishikesh Agrawani", 26)
parent.print_details()

"""
Details:-
Name:  Rishikesh Agrawani
Age:  26
Inside method of TopClass
"""

child.self_caller()
child.super_caller()

"""
Inside method of BottomClass
<super: <class 'BottomClass'>, <BottomClass object>>
Inside method of TopClass
"""
```

Answer (score 7):

`super().method()` will call the parent classes implementation of `method`, even if the child has defined their own.  You can read the [documentation for `super`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super) for a more in-depth explanation.

```
class Parent:
    def foo(self):
        print("Parent implementation")

class Child(Parent):
    def foo(self):
        print("Child implementation")
    def parent(self):
        super().foo()
    def child(self):
        self.foo()

c = Child()
c.parent()
# Parent implementation
c.child()
# Child implementation
```

For singular-inheritance classes like `Child`, `super().foo()` is the same as the more explicit `Parent.foo(self)`.  In cases of multiple inheritance, `super` will determine which `foo` definition to use based on the [Method Resolution Order, or MRO](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/).

A further motivating example: which method gets called if we subclass `Child` and write another implementation of `foo`?

```
class Grandchild(Child):
    def foo(self):
        print("Grandchild implementation")

g = Grandchild()
g.parent()
# Parent implementation
g.child()
# Grandchild implementation
```

Comment: @Afterlook I think in that case they're identical.

Comment: @Afterlook if the child is lacking an explicit implementation of a method you don't use `super` for "normal" usage because the fact that the method is looked up in a parent class is an implementation detail. You only use `super` when you explicitly and consciously need the parent class implementation.

Comment: The follow up questions that were answered by @PatrickHaugh and @timgeb were about when `super` and `self` produce the same results and the case when to use one over the other. I deleted the comments because I decided to explore on my own. Didn't expect you guys to be co quick. Thanks.

Comment: Hey Patrick, just saw you earned the gold Python badge a couple of hours ago. Contrags! Have fun wielding Mjolnir ;-)